# In clause of a select but with more than one value to look for

Tags: sql, select, plsql, where-clause, select-into

I have a set of results that I query with connect by prior, now I need to check in the where clause of a query if ONE of those results is IN  some other set of values(a select * from another table). I'm trying to use 'IN' but I think that that only works when I have one unique value to check for, and not a group of values.

```
SELECT COUNT('X')
INTO V_COUNT 
FROM SIC_NEA_CATFRU
WHERE (SELECT cod_nivel_estr_art
       FROM niveles_estr_art
       CONNECT BY PRIOR cod_nivel_estr_art_P = cod_nivel_estr_art
       START WITH cod_nivel_estr_art = V_COD_NIVEL_eSTR_ART) IN ( SELECT COD_NIVEL_eSTR_ART FROM SIC_NEA_CATFRU);
```

Answer (score 1):

Would the `intersect` set operator do? Something like this: first query is your hierarchical query, while the second returns values from the `sic_nea_catfru` table. If there are any matches, you'll know how many:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
  INTO v_count
  FROM (    SELECT cod_nivel_estr_art
              FROM niveles_estr_art
        CONNECT BY PRIOR cod_nivel_estr_art_p = cod_nivel_estr_art
        START WITH cod_nivel_estr_art = v_cod_nivel_estr_art
        INTERSECT
        SELECT cod_nivel_estr_art FROM sic_nea_catfru)
```

Comment: Thansk a lot!!! that'll do it! :)